# Pixel coordinates of image based on image, not screen, of finger touch

Tags: html, typescript, cordova

I am creating an app on the android platform and I need to print out the pixel coordinate of where a finger touches the image. The image is in a scrollable  tag, and right now, with a touchstart event listener, if I touch one spot on the screen and then scroll and touch the same spot (different part of the image but located on the same spot as the first touch) returns the same coordinates. So the calculations are done based on the screen, not the image. I've been told to do offsets based on where it is in the screen and the scroll, but when I run the app on a phone instead of a tablet, this will give me a different coordinate on each device. I do not know the size of the image as the user uploads any image they would like. I cannot show code, so I hope my description is enough to understand what I need.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you right, you want to get the "tapped" (clicked) coordinates inside your Image, where e.g. your left upper image corner is your 0:0 coordinate?

Also I hope jQuery is ok, if not I'm sorry but at least should give you some direction.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //I've added click event so you can see it here, but touchstart should work as well
  $('img').on('touchstart click', function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var X = (e.pageX - offset.left);
    var Y = (e.pageY - offset.top);
    $('#coord').text('X: ' + X + ', Y: ' + Y);
  });
});

//$(this).offset() gets the clicked elements (image) coordinates relative to the document
//e.pageX gets the cursor/finger click position relative from left edge of document
//e.pageY gets the cursor/finger click position relativ efrom top edge of document
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: white;
}

.image-container {
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-container"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/O%20https://placeholder.com/" /></div>
  <div>
    <div id="coord"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically you are just substracting the image coordinates (top left corner from image relative to document) from the clicked coordinates.

Comment: Would this answer give the same result if you touched the dead center of the image when it's running on a tv screen and when it's running on a cell phone? I mean, is the pixel coordinate based on the number of pixels in the screen, or does the image file determine the coordinate of each spot on the image

Comment: I have no real devices with other resolutions, so I can't test it. But I think it depends on how you style the image. Fixed width: Should always output the same result. - Percentage width: Output is different on all resolutions. So basically it depends on the width/height of the image. But as an example if your image is 500px * 500px on all resolutions (media queries), the result should be the same.